# Ampersand (&) breaks \ifdefined

Tags: latex

I am working on a document that is used in a lecture each semester. The contents basically stay the same, but only a subset of the content is used each semester.

Defines are used to set which parts should be compiled and which not. In one part of the document a list of the options is compiled in a tabular in the following form:

```
\ifdefined\whatever Title & -- & Description \\ \fi
```

So all options that are chosen via defines are listed in the table as a row.

The problem that occurs is that the `&` character seems to break the `\ifdefined` and is treated as a `\fi`. An `Incomplete \ifdefined` error is thrown.

I worked around this by defining a command that just outputs the `&` char. But there sure is a better way. Note that I am working on someone elses document and cannot just change the whole structure and the use of defines to reach this specific goal.

Comment: [This example](https://pastebin.com/zdFB95ZE) works without problem. Are you able to produce code (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that replicates your problematic behaviour?

Comment: I just tried to replicate it and noticed the document uses a custom documentclass I cannot publish. Trying to replicate it with a standard documentclass is no success, so the problem probably lies there. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: Without more detail, there's no way for the community to help since we can't replicate the behaviour.

Comment: Can you please include a complete example of what you are trying to do?